# Dummit and Foote 12.2.16: Determining all $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb F _{19}$ of order $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, characteristic-polynomial

This is exercise 12.2.16 of Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote.

> Show that $x^5-1 =(x-1)(x^2-4x+1)(x^2+5x+1)$ in $\mathbb F_{19}[x]$. Use this to determine, up to similarity, all $2 \times 2$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb F_{19}$ of (multiplicative order) $5$.

1. First of all, the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{19}$ is $C_{18}$, the cyclic group of order 18, with generator $2$, so I presume they mean that the matrices are of order $5$.
2. Secondly, I prove the decomposition result as stated and then see that due to Cayley-Hamilton we know that any $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ with minimal polynomial that divides $x^5-1$ must also satisfy $A^5-I=0  \implies A^5= I$.

The candidate polynomials are:
$x-1$, $x^2-4x+1$ and $x^2+5x+1$.

This question is similar to what they do on page 487, but I am not quite sure how one goes from these candidates to the list of permissible invariant factors, and after that, the matrices.

Comment: 1. The elements of order $5$, i.e., with $A^5=I$, but $A\neq I$. So which elements of $GL_2(\Bbb F_{19})$ have order $5$.

Comment: Thanks, I realised that the other option did not make sense. so one would determine the matrices first and then see if $A^5=I$, just like what Cayley Hamilton tells us.

Comment: Look up companion matrices, p. 475 in Dummit and Foote.

Comment: $b_0 + b_1 x + x^2$ corresponds to  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -b_0 \\ 1 & - b_1  \end{pmatrix} 
This gives me the matrices $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1& 4 \end{pmatrix} \equiv \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 18 \\ 1& 4 \end{pmatrix}   $$
and 
 $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1& -5 \end{pmatrix} \equiv  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 18 \\ 1& 14 \end{pmatrix}  $$

Comment: We can also have two blocks where $a_1=a_2=x+b_0=x-1$ since $x-1 |x-1$, we know that each gets their own $1\times 1$ block (just $-b_0=1$), this leads to the identity matrix $I$. But I do not think this counts as "having order $5$"

Comment: All these $3$ matrices indeed satisfy that $A^5=I$.

Comment: @WesleyStrik If you think you've figured out your question, consider posting an answer below. That way you can get feedback on your answer, and the question will be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We looks at the divisors of $x^5-1$ and use the decomposition as given. Notice for a $2 \times 2$ matrix it is only possible to get $2$ blocks of size $1$ or $1$ block of size $2\times 2$.

Recall that for a polynomial of the form $b_0 +b_1x +x^2$, we get the following companion matrix according to page 475:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -b_0 \\
    1 & -b_1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
A $1\times 1$ block simply has the value of $-b_0$ for $b_0 + x$.

- $x-1$, $x-1$ give us:
  $$\begin{pmatrix}
      -(-1) & 0 \\
      0 & -(-1) 
      \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 
      \end{pmatrix}=I.$$
  This matrix is of course not of order $5$, but of order $1$, therefore it satisfies $I^5=I$.
- $x^2-4x+1$ gives us:
  $$A= \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 \\
  1 & 4 
  \end{pmatrix}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 18 \\
  1 & 4 
  \end{pmatrix} \bmod {19}$$
- $x^2+5x+1$ gives us:
  $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 \\
  1 & -5 
  \end{pmatrix}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 18 \\
  1 & 14 
  \end{pmatrix} \bmod {19}$$
  One can easily verify that
  $$ A^5 \equiv B^5 \equiv 1$$
  Since $5$ ia prime and the matrices are nonidentity, this is the order.

Comment: Nice writeup. You might want to say why this gives *all* such matrices up to similarity. (This is basically due to the fact that every matrix can be conjugated into rational canonical form.)